# Rounding a number to a smaller or bigger size with the same ratio

Tags: c#, math, floating-point, int

I don't know how to describe it very well (so I can't look it up) but I need help. Lets say I have 100 out of 0 to 200, how do I ratio the number to 0 to 100 so it would be like 50? Simply ratio-ing the number to a smaller or bigger size?

Comment: Did you try _anything_? I don't see any programming question in here..

Comment: I dont think this is the place for this question, but try something like (x-x1)/(x2-x1)*(nx2-nx1) which relates to something like (100-0)/(200-0)*(100-0)

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the ratio between the original maximum and the new maximum:

```
double k = (double)newMax / (double)oldMax
```

In your example you would end up with the value `0.5`.

Then just multiply the value with the ratio:

```
double newValue = value * k;
```

If you want an integer value, round it and convert to integer:

```
int newValue = (int)Math.Round(value * k);
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, when the minimum is not necessarily 0 on either the 'old' and 'new scales', the solution is the following:

ratio = ( oldValue - oldMin ) / ( oldMax - oldMin )

newValue = newMin + ( newMax - newMin ) * ratio

Answer (score 0):

```
double myRatio, maxValue, newValue;
//value retrieval logics.
double result = (myRatio / maxValue) * newMaxValue;
```

u gotta fill the doubles on the first line in.
this is the shortest code I'd say.

Answer (score -1):

```
((Max - value) / Max) * (newMax)
```

Comment: No. This would only work if the value is exactly half the max. But `(value/Max) * newMax` would work, if the min is zero.